# "too much time in trenches"

Tags: idioms

What does this idiom mean?

> too much time in trenches.

Example usage:

> This might just be bad bias on my part though. Expert practitioners can be terrible at forecasting. Too much time in trenches.

Comment: It should probably say 'too much time in _the_ trenches'.

Comment: probably doth butter no parsnips

Answer (score 1):

Historically, trenches refer to warfare, especially WWI.  Too much time in trenches suggests someone has been so deep in the topic, perhaps keeping his head down,  that he is no longer able to make accurate, objective judgments.

Comment: I was going to say the same thing, but didn't have any references. Did you manage to find any? If so, you could [edit them in](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/403419/edit)...

Comment: I could understand it to mean "seen too many things go wrong", and in this instance where it is used as a negative trait to forecasting (I'm not sure I remember it being used that way too frequently...but sometimes) might mean "overly pessimistic"... I feel like I hear it more often meaning "~wise~ because you've seen what could go wrong"